# In Next.js 13 with turbopack, how do I access cookies without getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have an app that persists some values in a cookie. I know that there are other tools such as `useState`, `useContext`, etc... but this particular app works with a library that stores information in a jwt so I have to read certain values by fetching the jwt. I am porting the app from next.js 12 (with webpack) to next.js 13 (with turbopack).

I've already ported the app structurally to fit the `app` style routing of next.js 13. My pages all go in their individual folders with sub layouts WITHIN the `app` directory, and I have a master layout and homepage directly in the `app` directory.

The old code for my protected page in next.js 12 looked like this:

protected.tsx

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { useContext } from 'react';

//@ts-ignore
import Cookies from 'cookies';

const Protected: NextPage = (props: any) => {
  if (!props.authorized) {
    return (
      <h2>Unauthorized</h2>
    )
  } else {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-md">
      <h1 className="font-bold">This is the Protected Section</h1>
    </div>
  )}
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ req, res, query }) => {
  const { id } = query
  const cookies = new Cookies(req, res)
  const jwt = cookies.get('<MY TOKEN NAME>')
  if (!jwt) {
    return {
      props: {
        authorized: false
      },
    }
  }

  const { verified } = <MY TOKEN SDK INSTANCE>.verifyJwt({ jwt })

  return {
    props: {
      authorized: verified ? true : false
    },
  }
}

export default Protected
```

I have this page moved into it's own directory now.

"getServerSideProps" isn't supported in Next.js 13 https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals. The docs say "previous Next.js APIs such as getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, and getInitialProps are not supported in the new app directory." So how would I change my code to work in Next.js 13?

P.S. I know what it looks like but this cookie IS NOT HANDLING USER AUTHENTICATION. I understand that someone could alter the cookie and gain access to the protected page. This is just a small piece of a larger app with other security mechanisms that I have in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
```

this is `next/headers.js` cookie function

```
function cookies() {
    (0, _staticGenerationBailout).staticGenerationBailout('cookies');
    const requestStore = _requestAsyncStorage.requestAsyncStorage && 'getStore' in _requestAsyncStorage.requestAsyncStorage ? _requestAsyncStorage.requestAsyncStorage.getStore() : _requestAsyncStorage.requestAsyncStorage;
    return requestStore.cookies;
}
```

this is making a request to the client side to get the cookie. In `app` directory, you are on the server and you can write this inside the component.

```
const cookie = cookies().get("cookieName")?.value
```

Comment: According to the error I'm getting, next doesn't seem to have a `cookies()` function...? Idk why, but this is the source code for my page https://gist.github.com/ChristianOConnor/a44adc4d98c807ba63d09392ca8824bb. And I'm getting this error `Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')` https://imgur.com/a/WgnC24Z.

Comment: `has` is used for sets. looks like it is not a set. can you pls just `console.log(cookies().get("cookieName")?.value)`

Comment: I get the same error but I just realized that maybe my cookie isn't getting set? I try to set the cookie in another file like this `cookies().set('lit-auth', litjwt, { expires: 1 });`. But I just realized that according to the docs "The cookies function allows you to read the HTTP incoming request cookies from a server component. It is read-only, meaning you cannot set / delete the outgoing request cookies."... So how do I set the cookie in Next.js 13?

Comment: you can check chrome dev tools cookies

Comment: Yeah I checked no cookies... So how do I set the cookie?

Comment: you can find any cookie library. every cookie library has `set` method

Comment: I fixed it, I set the cookie with `cookies-next` and I'm able to fetch the cookie exactly as you suggested. It works fine with webpack, but it just doesn't work with turbopack. With turbopack I get `TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null` which doesn't make sense... Anyway thanks for the help. I'm accepting your answer now.

Comment: Doesn't work with client components ("use client") though. That's relevant because data-fetching for them happens on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

you can access to your cookie via `"cookies-next"` library.

pnpm i cookies-next

check this out : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next